# Map array of objects to new structure grouped by timestamp

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Given the following array of objects:

```
const array = [
  {
    timestamp: '2016-01-01',
    itemID: 'AA',
    value: 20,
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2016-01-01',
    itemID: 'AB',
    value: 32,
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2016-01-02',
    itemID: 'ABC',
    value: 53
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2016-01-02',
    itemID: 'ABCD',
    value: 51
  }
]
```

I would like to return the following result:

```
const result = [
  {
    timestamp: '2016-01-01',
    AA: 20,
    AB: 32,
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2016-01-02',
    ABC: 53,
    ABCD: 51
  }
]
```

I managed to make the following:

```js
const array = [
  {
    timestamp: '2016-01-01',
    itemID: 'AA',
    value: 20,
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2016-01-01',
    itemID: 'AB',
    value: 32,
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2016-01-02',
    itemID: 'ABC',
    value: 53
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2016-01-02',
    itemID: 'ABCD',
    value: 51
  }
]

var res = [];

array.forEach(function(element) {
  var e = res.find(function(e) {
     return e.timestamp == element.timestamp;
  });
  console.log(e)
  if(e) {
     
  } else {
     res.push({
       [element.timestamp]: element.timestamp,
       [element.itemID]: element.value
     });
  }  
});

console.log(res, '');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an object - grouping by timestamp and the mapping it back to an array, like:

```
let mapByTimestamp = array.reduce((res, item) => {
  res[item.timestamp] = res[item.timestamp] || {};

  Object.assign(res[item.timestamp], {
    [item.itemID]: item.value
  });

  return res;
}, {});

Object.keys(mapByTimestamp)
    .map(timestamp => Object.assign(mapByTimestamp[timestamp], { timestamp }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert when it does not exist and update when it changes:

```
var output = [];

for (var index in array) {
    var found = false;
    for (var innerIndex in output) {
        if (output[innerIndex].timestamp === array[index].timestamp) {
            output[innerIndex][array[index].itemID] = array[index].value;
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        var newItem = {timestamp: array[index].timestamp};
        newItem[array[index].itemID] = array[index].value;
        output.push(newItem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a map for collecting the values.

```js
var array = [{ timestamp: '2016-01-01', itemID: 'AA', value: 20 }, { timestamp: '2016-01-01', itemID: 'AB', value: 32 }, { timestamp: '2016-01-02', itemID: 'ABC', value: 53 }, { timestamp: '2016-01-02', itemID: 'ABCD', value: 51 }],
    grouped = array.reduce((map => (r, a) => {
        var o = { timestamp: a.timestamp };
        if (!map.has(a.timestamp)) {
            map.set(a.timestamp, o);
            r.push(o);
        }
        map.get(a.timestamp)[a.itemID] = a.value;
        return r;
    })(new Map), []);

console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array.forEach(function(element) {
  var e = res.find(function(data) {
  return data.timestamp == element.timestamp;
});

if(e) {
  e[element.itemID] =  element.value;
} else {
 res.push({
   timestamp: element.timestamp,
   [element.itemID]: element.value
 });
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = [];
array.forEach(function(element) {
  var e = res.find(function(e){
    return e.timestamp == element.timestamp;
  });
  if(e){
    e[element.itemID] = element.value;
  }
  else{
    e = {};
    e.timestamp = element.timestamp;
    e[element.itemID] = element.value;
    res.push(e);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [
  {
    timestamp: '2016-01-01',
    itemID: 'AA',
    value: 20,
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2016-01-01',
    itemID: 'AB',
    value: 32,
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2016-01-02',
    itemID: 'ABC',
    value: 53
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2016-01-02',
    itemID: 'ABCD',
    value: 51
  }
]

var res = [];



array.forEach(function(element) {
  var e = res.find(function(e) {
     return e.timestamp == element.timestamp;
  });
  if(e === undefined){
   res.push({
    'timestamp':element.timestamp,
    [element.itemID]:element.value
   });
  }else{
   e[element.itemID] = element.value;
  }
});

console.log(res, '');
```

there, i fixed your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows;

```js
var array = [
  {
    timestamp: '2016-01-01',
    itemID: 'AA',
    value: 20,
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2016-01-01',
    itemID: 'AB',
    value: 32,
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2016-01-02',
    itemID: 'ABC',
    value: 53
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2016-01-02',
    itemID: 'ABCD',
    value: 51
  }
],
 interim = array.reduce((p,c) => Object.assign(p, {[c.timestamp]: p[c.timestamp] ? Object.assign(p[c.timestamp], {[c.itemID]: c.value})
                                                                                 : {[c.itemID]: c.value, timestamp: c.timestamp}}),{});
  result = Object.keys(interim)
                 .map(k => interim[k]);
console.log(result);
```